# Create an unmodified object in a Firefox addon using WebExtensions

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-addons

I'm building an addon that works on a page where the `canvas` element prototype has been modified, this means any new `canvas` element I create on the page or in the addon with have the same modified state.

Is there a way to get around this? I tried using `eval()` but it also uses the page "version" of the `HTMLCanvasElement`.

To get around it in the browser manually I can create an `iframe` and execute a script inside it that sets a variable on the parent window which I can then of course `.call()` with the context I want, the problem is that WebExtensions doesn't allow access to variables set by page scripts.

Answer (score 0):

After some more reading I found out that there's a property called `wrappedJSObject` that allows the content script to access properties set by the page script.

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Accessing_page_script_objects_from_content_scripts